# bibliographystyle 'splncs04': URLs citation

Tags: bibtex, lncs

I am using **bibliographystyle 'splncs04'**

I want to cite few URLs. I don't know how to include URLs in bibtex file?
Below is a part of my latex file and Bibtex file

Latex File:

```
  \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{program}
  \usepackage{url}

  \begin{document}
  : 
  \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
  \bibliography{mybibliography} 
  \end{document}
```

**mybibliography.bib** is a plain Text file with entries as follows:

```
  @inproceedings{jianqiang2015pre,
  title={Pre-processing boosting Twitter sentiment analysis?},
  author={Jianqiang, Zhao},
  booktitle={2015 IEEE International Conference on Smart 
  City/SocialCom/SustainCom (SmartCity)},
  pages={748--753},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
  }

  @article{singh2016role,
  title={Role of text pre-processing in twitter sentiment analysis},
  author={Singh, Tajinder and Kumari, Madhu},
  journal={Procedia Computer Science},
  volume={89},
  pages={549--554},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `@online`, as with biblatex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "cite [a] few URLs". Do you intend to cite some online publications or resources for which you have URLs that point to the publications' web pages? Please advise.

Comment: I want to cite technical online documentation like any "R" package

Comment: `splncs04.bst` supports the `url` field. For most entry types it should be enough to just add `url = {http://example.com/mylink.html},` to the `.bib` entry to get the URL in the bibliography. If that does not work, it would be great if you could share a short example document that shows what exactly you are trying at the moment (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and how that does not work for you.

Comment: I want to cite this URL - "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf"

Comment: OK, and does that not work if you create a new `@misc` entry with `url = {https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf},`? In a short test it seemed to work for me and gave acceptable output.

Comment: I added: @misc{ref_url,
url = {https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf}
}

Comment: But this has no effect on References section. URL is not showing up there.